# python - invalid syntax when I use *

Tags: python, python-2.7

I created a simple function to unpack N elements from an iterable.

```
def drop_first_last(grades):
    grades = first, *middle, last
    return avg(middle)
```

When I run this function occurred following error:

```
grades = first, *middle, last

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know why this error occurred, how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe remove the `*` ?

Comment: I think your assignment is backwards. You're assigning to grades, not using grades to get values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do:

```
middle = grades[1:-1]
return avg(middle)
```

Comment: in python 3 you can do `first,*middle,last = grades` but the question is python2.7 so the answer is right

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that this isn't Python syntax! The `*` notation is used to declare variable numbers of arguments and to unpack tuples. You are trying to use it to do something like the [pattern matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) found in functional languages like Haskell. Plus the assignment is backwards, as @thegrinner noted.